# How to search through subarrays efficiently in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = array($arr1,$arr2,..);
```

How to search through `$arr` to find the one with `key1 => 'something'`,`key2 => 'something else'`

Comment: The best way will depend on the type of data this subarrays have. If for example the values for the given key are sorted you can use binary search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Answer (score 5):

You can iterate over a nested array with [Iterators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php), e.g.

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveArrayIterator($nestedArray), 
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $key => val) {
    if($key === 'something') {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, have a look at [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)