# how to use in_array for subarrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to verify if a value is inside an array, and I'm using the php function `in_array()` for it. I noticed it doesn't work when the array I send to the `in_array()` function is composed by subarrays.
Is there anyway to do this verification for subarrays?
To help you to understand my problem, I have the following code:

```
$userIds = array();
foreach($accounts as $account){
    $accounIds[] = $account->getId();
    $userIds[] = AccountUserBeanHome::findAllIdsByAccountId($account->getId());
}
$userId = 225;
if (in_array($userId, $userIds, true)) {
    do action...
}
```

The problem is that the array $userIds may be something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 225
        [1] => 226
        [2] => 227
        [3] => 228
        [4] => 229
        [5] => 230
        [6] => 340
        [7] => 355
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 313
        [1] => 314
        [2] => 315
        [3] => 316
        [4] => 318
        [5] => 319
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 298
        [1] => 301
        [2] => 302
        [3] => 338
    )

)
```

I noticed `in_array()` doesnt work to check sub-arrays, so I'd like your help to do this verification... maybe a way to make all the subarrays elements become all elements of the main array... well.. I hope u can help me.

Comment: Why don't you flat `$userIds` array?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, @Florent, but what do you mean by flat in this case?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English too, I mean **flatten**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten `$userIds` array using `array_merge()`:

```
$userIds[] = array();
foreach($accounts as $account){
    $accounIds[] = $account->getId();
    $userIds = array_merge($userIds, AccountUserBeanHome::findAllIdsByAccountId($account->getId()));
}
```

Then call `in_array()` to check your id.

Comment: This solution fits well too.. and at first, I was trying to find a way to do exactly this, @Florent, but now I have this doubt of which solution may be the best one...

Comment: Using SPL (see @Martijn answer) is always more elegant but harder to understand when you're not fully comfortable with PHP. Think about the future of your application to choose the right solution.

Answer (score 12):

What you need is a recursive in_array.
Luckily, many people have made this already.

This one is directly from the PHP manual comments section: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#84602

```
<?php 
function in_array_recursive($needle, $haystack) { 
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($haystack)); 
    foreach($it AS $element) { 
        if($element == $needle) { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: It worked well, @Martijn, and I just added this function in my library. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveArrayIterator($userIds), 
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $key => $val) {
    if($val == $userId) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Documentation about [recursiveiteratoriterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).

Kudo's to [gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416306/657496)