# What is the proper way to use PHP iterators to implement identical functionality to the 'array_walk_recursive()' function?

Tags: php, arrays, iterator

I need to iterate recursively through all array elements (i.e., for every array element encountered that is itself an array, I need to iterate through that array) and perform a `trim()` on every string (leaf) value.

To use a very similar example to the one noted in the link just below, this is what I need:

```
<?php

    
    // How to accomplish identical functionality using PHP iterators?


    $sweet = array('a' => ' apple ', 'b' => ' banana ');
    $fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => ' lemon ');
    
    function my_trim(&$item, $key)
    {
        // Trim the whitespace from the values
        $item = trim($item);
    }
    
    array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'my_trim');

?>
```

The function [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) provides exactly the functionality that I need.

However, I'd like to understand PHP iterators better, and my current task seems like a good opportunity to do so by using iterators to implement identical functionality to the `array_walk_recursive()` function.

When I go to the [PHP documentation for iterators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php), I see various iterators but no overall description of their semantics.  In particular, the [RecursiveArrayIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) seems like the obvious choice, and if it wasn't for the [RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) class and [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2416306/368896) to a similar question (which gives the code but does not explain the code to my satisfaction), I would simply have attempted to use the former iterator (`RecursiveArrayIterator`), and I might not even have posted this question.

However, in my attempt to actually look at the **documentation** for the two relevant iterator classes - `RecursiveArrayIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` - in order to understand the code in the above link and be satisfied to use it (or not) - I have found no documentation of the semantics of these iterators anywhere in my Google search (in particular, I see no introductory documentation of either of these iterators in the official PHP documentation, as noted above).

Therefore, I'd like to know **what is the proper way to use PHP iterators to implement identical functionality to the `array_walk_recursive()` function**.  (Presumably, if the code at the above SO link is correct, it will be exactly (or similar to) the linked code - but I'd like not just a code snippet, but also a (brief) explanation.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a simple way to use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` to modify the original array, instead `array_walk_recursive` as used your example is a better option.

If you want to only access the leaves of a multidimensional array w/o modifying the original array, you can use the `LEAVES_ONLY` option.

```
$sweet = array('a' => ' apple ', 'b' => ' banana ');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => ' lemon ');

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
             new RecursiveArrayIterator($fruits),
             RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
         ) as $key => $value) {
    print trim($value);
}
```

Note that in the `foreach` above it would be illegal to reference $value i.e. `as $key => &$value`, in which case php will produce the following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference
```

`RecursiveIteratorIterator` recursively iterates over any recursive object that implements the [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php) (and by extension [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)) interface . For nested arrays you'll want an `RecursiveArrayIterator` iterator object
but you could also have `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to traverse a filesystem for example.

The path you traverse the object can be specified by the 2nd argument to `RecursiveIteratorIterator`:

```
RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY - The default. Lists only leaves in iteration.
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST - Lists leaves and parents in iteration with parents coming first.
RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST - Lists leaves and parents in iteration with leaves coming first.
```

Answer (score 1):

An Iterator is not meant to modify it's inner elements. An Iterator is used for accessing a collection of elements one by one in a foreach loop.

Of course you could override the `current()` function of the Iterator in a way that returns a modified version of the string. However, you would still need to iterate over all elements by your own to modify them.

I'll try to explain by example:

```
$sweet = array('a' => ' apple ', 'b' => ' banana ');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => ' lemon ');
```

Create a customized `RecursiveIteratorIterator`:

```
class CallbackRecursiveIteratorIterator extends
    RecursiveIteratorIterator
{

    public function __construct(RecursiveIterator $it, $callback) {
        $this->callback = $callback;
        parent::__construct($it);
    }   

    public function current() {
        return $this->callback->__invoke(parent::current());
    }   

}
```

Create an instance of that Iterator:

```
$i = new CallbackRecursiveIteratorIterator (
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(
            $fruits
    ),  
    // pass callback here
    function($element) {
        return trim($element . " test");
    }   
);


// Iterate over modified values
foreach($i as $key => $el) {
    var_dump($el);
}
```

Note that the original array is still unchanged:

```
var_dump($fruits);
```